# Every singleton is the intersection of a decreasing sequence of basic open sets

Tags: general-topology

If I have a nice (meaning Hausdorff, second-countable, and locally compact) space $E$, then I know that there is a countable base consisting of relatively compact sets $\mathcal{B}:=\{U_n : n\geq1\}$.

If I pick any $x\in E$, is there a sequence $( V_n )_n$ of base sets such that $V_n\to\{x\}$? That is, $V_1\supseteq V_2\supseteq\cdots$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n = \{x\}$.

Comment: On Math.Stackexchange, we look for well-asked questions. These should include not only a statement of a problem, but also motivation and/or context of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $T_1$ $X$ space it holds that $\bigcap \{U ⊆ X$ open$: x ∈ U\} = \{x\}$. And for any base $\mathcal{B}$ and any $x ∈ U ⊆ X$, where $U$ is open, there is $B ∈ \mathcal{B}$ such that $x ∈ B ⊆ U$. So if $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, you have your sequence.

Comment: Ha! Ok, I got it, thx a lot! :)